# How do I apply my background image to putty tabs in conemu?

Tags: putty, desktop-customization, conemu

Here's conemu looking fabulous on a command window.
[image: screenshot 1]

But we lose the background image in a putty tab?
[image: screenshot 2]

What should I do to get the background image applied to all of my tabs?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html

Answer (score 1):

Putty doesn't support background images and transparency, you can use [Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) instead.

Comment: @SkipL have a look here http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=covidimus&zone=en